# How to make admin interface language always english for Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a Drupal site with en,ja and ko languages enabled. If I edit any translation (say korea)  the entire admin interface changes to Korea language. How can I disable this in Drupal 8. I want the site admin interface in English.

I tried with setting administration page language to English under user , but after making this change I can see only English text loads while editing the Korea translation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Account administration pages" at http://my.local/en/admin/config/regional/language/detection and place it in the first position

[image]

Set a value for "Administration pages language" on the user profile (ie http://my.local/en/user/1/edit)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the following configuration did it for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Admin toolbar** module, checkout this issues.
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2313309
https://www.drupal.org/project/administration_language_negotiation/issues/2909247